# How to calculate the parameters of the equivalent circuit from the no-load measurement of the induction motor?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, induction-motor, electric-machine

I would like to determine the values of the parameters of the magnetizing branch of the equivalent circuit of the induction motor based on the no-load measurement. Based on the *Electric Motor Control* book I should follow the below given steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My problem is that I don't understand how those formulas have been derived. Based on the equivalent circuit for the no-load condtions I would say that the impedance in the no-load condition is

$$\hat{Z}_{N_{01}} = R_s + i\cdot X_{ls} + \frac{i\cdot X_m\cdot R_c}{R_c + i\cdot X_m}$$

But based on the last formula in the book mentioned above I would say that the author somehow suppose that the impedance in the no-load condition is

$$\hat{Z}_{N_{02}} = (R_s + R_c) + i\cdot(X_{ls} + X_m)$$

I suspect that some simplifying assumptions have been applied to the \$\hat{Z}_{N_{01}}\$ and the formula \$\hat{Z}_{N_{02}}\$ resulted. Unfortunately I am not able to find those assumptions. Can anybody help?